# wordpress display posts on subcategory only

Tags: php, wordpress

hi I'm using Wordpress on developing a site and a self made template. I got 1 page to display all categories with its post. this is what i want to do

- Main Category

  - subcategory1

    - post 1
    - subcategory1.2

      - post 1.2.1
      - post 1.2.2
  - subcategory2
  - subcategory3

i use `wp_link_category()` to display the category and i search how to display category with post but the problem is. the post from subcategory 1.2 is also display on subcategory 1

- Main Category

  - subcategory1

    - post 1
    - post 1.2.1
    - post 1.2.2
    - subcategory1.2

      - post 1.2.1
      - post 1.2.2
  - subcategory2
  - subcategory3

how can i remove the post from subcategory 1.2 on subcategory 1?
here's the code i copy and paste from stackoverflow

```
$categories =  get_categories('child_of=4');  
foreach  ($categories as $category) {
    //Display the sub category information using $category values like $category->cat_name
    echo '<h2>'.$category->name.'</h2>';
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach (get_posts('cat='.$category->term_id) as $post) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';   
    }  
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

i hope you understand my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
$args = array(
  'child_of' => 4,
  'parent' => 4
  );

$categories =  get_categories( $args );
```

Comment: What does it output? What happens when you restrict it to just `parent=4`, no `child_of`?

Comment: no output sir.. i try `parent_of=4` nothing change.. output still the same

Comment: i didn't say `parent_of`, I said `parent`

Comment: hmm, strange. what about `parent=0`?